# subscribers counter in pure javascript without jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

adding counter to my page in pure javascript by the following code:

```
    window.onload = function () {
    var subs = 663965;
    setInterval(function() {
        var ftr = getElementById('subscribers');
        subs++;
        ftr.innerHTML(subs);
    }, 3000);
}


    <footer id = "subscribers">663965</footer>
```

Comment: `document.getElementById`

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot the document in `document.getElementById('subscribers');` and also setting the text content of `ftr` using `ftr.textContent = subs;`

```html
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <script>
      window.onload = function () {
        var subs = 663965;
        setInterval(function() {
          var ftr = document.getElementById('subscribers');
          subs++;

          ftr.textContent = subs;
        }, 3000);
      }
    </script>

    <footer id="subscribers">663965</footer>
  </body>
</html>
```